# Publishing Powershell Modules to VSTS Package Management using Publish-Module

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, package-managers

I am trying to publish my Powershell modules to a VSTS Package Management feed. So far I have:

```
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $RepositoryPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($RepositoryUsername, $securePass)


Write-Debug "Adding the Repository $RepositoryName"
Register-PSRepository -Name $RepositoryName -SourceLocation $RepositorySourceUri `
                            -PublishLocation $RepositoryPublishUri -Credential $cred `
                          -PackageManagementProvider Nuget -InstallationPolicy Trusted

$PublishParams = @{
    Path = $ModuleFolderPath
    ProjectUri = $ProjectUri
    Tags = $ModuleTags
    Repository = $RepositoryName
    NugetApiKey = $NugetApiKey
}

Publish-Module @PublishParams -Force -Verbose
```

However, I get the following error:

> Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to publish module
>   'Framework.Logging': 'Publishing to a ********   package management
>   feed
>   'https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/PowershellModules/nuget/v2'
>   requires it to be   registered as a NuGet package source. Retry after
>   adding this source
>   'https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/PowershellModules/nuget/v2'
>   as NuGet package source by following the   instructions specified at
>   'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=698608''.  At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.1.2.0\PSModule.psm1:1227
>   char:17  + Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `  +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  + CategoryInfo
>   : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException  +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   FailedToPublishTheModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility

The PSRepository is passed https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/PowershellModules/nuget/v2 as both the source and publish Uris when it is created. Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling this command to add package source with NuGet.exe tool:

1. Download Nuget.exe to a folder
2. Open Command Prompt and navigate (CD) to that folder

command:

```
.\nuget.exe sources add -name [sourcename, such as myPSModuleFeed] -source https://[account].pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/[feedname]/nuget/v2 -username test -password [PAT] -storePasswordInClearText
```

Article about Personal Access token: [Authenticate access with personal access tokens for Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate)

Comment: Thanks, however that doesn't register the feed as a PSRepository. Does VSTS Package Management work with publishing via PowerShellGet (Publish-Module) or is the only way to currently publish to Package Management via Nuget.exe?

Comment: @Carl You don't need to update your code, still use it. What I mean is that you need to add the feed to Nuget sources (not publish) and Publish-Module works fine for me. You can check the sources in Nuget.config file (%appdata%\nugget foder)

Comment: @Carl The workflow is that 1. Call Nuget command to add sources (just one time) 2. Run your PowerShell script

Comment: Thanks, that all seems good now :) thanks for your help. For future ref I've posted my full implementation here: http://trycatchexfinally.co.uk/posts/publishing-powershell-modules-to-vsts-package-management